# How to optimize query for Max(Date) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT company.*, salesorder.lastOrderDate
FROM company
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT companyId, MAX(orderDate) AS lastOrderDate 
FROM salesorder
GROUP BY companyId
) salesorder ON salesorder.companyId = company.companyId;
```

This gives me one extra column at the end of a company master table with their last order date.

Problem is, when analyzing this query, it seems like it's not that efficient:

[image]

Is there a way to make this more efficient?

```
salesorder:

orderId, companyId, orderDate
1          333      2015-01-01
2          555      2016-01-01
3          333      2017-01-01


company

companyId, name
333        Acme
555        Microsoft


Query:

companyId, name,       lastOrderDate
333        Acme        2017-01-01
555        Microsoft   2016-01-01
```

EXPLAIN SELECT:
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `salesorder` (
  `orderId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `companyId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `orderId_UNIQUE` (`orderId`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `testComposite` (`companyId`,`orderDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `companyId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`companyId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `companyId_UNIQUE` (`companyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: May you add mockup data and table structures, so we can actually analyze performance?

Comment: this is done...

Comment: Is `orderdate` indexed? Apart from that, there's no way to make this more efficient since there are no restrictions - it the server has to scan *all* sales to find the maximum per company and then join with *all* companies.

Comment: Please post the table creation scripts. I'd expect the `companyId` columns to be indexed in both tables, so why does the server perform a full scan on `company` ?

Comment: orderdate is indexed... but what about order by desc limit 1? Is there any way I can leverage that?

Comment: Full scan on company is fine as I am selecting the entire company table...  companyId is indexed unique, and companyId is indexed on the sales order table too

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  There should not be two table scans.

Comment: @RickJames Done... There were never two table scans, there was a full index scan. I'm ok with the company table scan as it's a small table and I am actually selecting all the companies... it's the next one that's the issue.

Comment: A lateral join could do this efficiently, but MySql has been brain-dead since 2006. The other big DBs (Oracle, Sql Server, Postgresql) have all had the feature since at least 2012.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn how would you write the statement in MS-SQL?

Comment: Sql Server would use the APPLY keyword. MySql intends to eventually follow the Oracle syntax, which is different (LATERAL), but I haven't heard if it's implemented yet.

Comment: Actually, reading the question again, you don't need either. Just join directly to the salesorder table and GROUP BY all the company fields.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - for the record, MySQL 8.0.14 (released only a year ago) got a few more neurons -- it now has `LATERAL`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the *composite* index with the columns in this order:

```
INDEX(companyId, orderDate)
```

Single column indexes are not as efficient (in this query).

Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique key, do not redundantly declare a `UNIQUE` key.

With only a few rows in the table, you cannot trust `EXPLAIN` (and Explain-like output) to say how bad the query will be.  Try it with at least a few dozen rows.  And provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Note that it says "Using index".  That says that the subquery in question can be performed entirely inside the index's BTree.  This is 'good'.  (I presume you did the `EXPLAIN` after adding my suggested index?)

Your previous image showed a lot of rows; what gives?

I'm still puzzled as to why there are 3 rows in the `EXPLAIN` and two table scans.  Anyway, here is another formulation to try:

```
SELECT  c.*,
        ( SELECT MAX(orderDate)
              FROM salesorder
              WHERE companyId = c.companyId
        ) AS lastOrderDate
    FROM  company AS c;
```

(and my `INDEX` is still important)

Comment: Didn't make any difference.

Comment: I re-created the tables for demostration... but yes, the sales order table would have had 400K+ rows.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to try this too. Looks like it would do a subquery for each item in company table..Thanks

Comment: @trilogy - Yes; it is an alternative way that works nicely in _some_ situations.  Your original query _should_ have worked nicely, too; but I don't know why it did not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could simplify the query like this:

```
SELECT c.*, MAX(o.OrderDate) As lastOrderDate
FROM company c
INNER JOIN salesorder o on o.companyId = c.companyId
GROUP BY <list all company fields here>;
```

MySql might even let you get away with just `c.companyId` in the `GROUP BY` clause, but that's not really standard and not great practice.